# Increment date by one in such a way its next working/week day date

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, date, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark dataframes. I have a use case where I need to increment a date by one. I the incremental date happens to be weekend then I need to increment it to next week/working day.

```
val df = Seq(
  ("50312", "2021-12-01", "0.9992019"),
  ("50312", "2021-12-02", "0.20171201"),
  ("50312", "2021-12-03", "2.9992019")
).toDF("id","some_date","item_value")
.withColumn("nextworking_day", date_add(col("some_date"),1))
```

Next working day should be next weekday not weekend. How to do it?

Comment: Is Saturday a work day? What about holidays, in which country?

Comment: Only weekend , i.e. Saturday and Sunday , it should jump to Monday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `dayofweek` to get the number of the weekday and add 2 if the day is Saturday or add 3 if the day is Friday.

```scala
val day = dayofweek(col("some_date"))
val nextworkday = col("some_date") + when(day > 5, -day + 9).otherwise(1)
val df = Seq(
  ("50312", "2021-12-01", "0.9992019"),
  ("50312", "2021-12-02", "0.20171201"),
  ("50312", "2021-12-03", "2.9992019")
).toDF("id","some_date","item_value")
.withColumn("some_date", col("some_date").cast("date"))
.withColumn("nextworking_day", nextworkday)

df.show()
+-----+----------+----------+---------------+
|   id| some_date|item_value|nextworking_day|
+-----+----------+----------+---------------+
|50312|2021-12-01| 0.9992019|     2021-12-02|
|50312|2021-12-02|0.20171201|     2021-12-03|
|50312|2021-12-03| 2.9992019|     2021-12-06|
+-----+----------+----------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Writing an udf for checking the day should solve the problem
Below is the sample code running in pyspark, does not contain code for holidays but you can create a List or an enum and add a condition based on your region

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


@f.udf(returnType=TimestampType())
def get_convert_date_udf(date_column):
  datetime_object = datetime.strptime(date_column, "%Y-%m-%d")
  new_datetime_object = datetime_object + timedelta(days=1)
  day = new_datetime_object.strftime("%A")
  if day == "Sunday":
      new_datetime_object += timedelta(days=1)
  elif day == "Saturday":
      new_datetime_object += timedelta(days=2)
  return new_datetime_object


df = df.withColumn("next_working_date", 
get_convert_date_udf(f.col("some_date")))
```